# How to use multiple threads with shared data inside a loop in Vala?

Tags: multithreading, loops, parallel-processing, vala

I was wondering how I could take advantage of my cores to make loops run in parallel. Let's say I want to initialise all members of a big array to 1.
To check if the initialisation was done correctly, at the end, I add all the values of the array, but I get a zero. How can I make threads share the data?

Here's my attempt:

```
class Worker {
    public uint64[] arr;
    public uint64 start;
    public uint64 end;
    public int val;

    public Worker (ref uint64[] arr, uint64 start, uint64 end, int val) {
        this.arr = arr;
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
        this.val = val;
    }
}

void initialize (Worker p) {
    for (var i = p.start; i <= p.end; i++) {
        p.arr[i] = p.val;
    }
}

int main (string[] args) {

    var num_proc = (int) get_num_processors ();
    stdout.printf ("Using %d threads\n", num_proc);
    uint64 n = 50000000;
    var arr = new uint64[n];
    ulong microseconds;
    double seconds;
    var timer = new Timer ();

    try {
        var threads = new ThreadPool<Worker>.with_owned_data ((ThreadPoolFunc<Worker>) initialize, num_proc, true);
        for (var i = 0; i < num_proc; i++) {
            uint64 start = i * (n / num_proc);
            uint64 end = (i + 1) * (n / num_proc) - 1;
            if (i == num_proc - 1) end += n % num_proc;
            print (@"Thread $(i + 1): start: $start, end: $end (amount: $(end - start + 1))\n");
            threads.add (new Worker (ref arr, start, end, 1));
        }
    } catch (ThreadError e) {
        stderr.printf ("%s\n", e.message);
    }

    uint64 sum = 0;
    for (uint64 i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sum += arr[i];
    }
    stdout.printf ("sum: %llu\n", sum);

    timer.stop ();
    seconds = timer.elapsed (out microseconds);
    stdout.printf ("Time elapsed: %.3f seconds.\n", seconds);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array is copied here:

```
public Worker (ref uint64[] arr, uint64 start, uint64 end, int val) {
    this.arr = arr;
    this.start = start;
    this.end = end;
    this.val = val;
}
```

An assignment is creating a copy here. You can use an `unowned` variable to fix this:

```
class Worker {
    // The array is not owned by the worker!
    public unowned uint64[] arr;
    public uint64 start;
    public uint64 end;
    public int val;

    public Worker (ref uint64[] arr, uint64 start, uint64 end, int val) {
        this.arr = arr;
        this.start = start;
        this.end = end;
        this.val = val;
    }
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would work the parallel access on the array? Can it get corrupted?

Comment: That's a complicated topic. Basically as long as the threads operate on independent slices of the array there is no problem. Parallel read/write of overlapping slices have to be protected (i.e. using a GLib.Mutex or similar). It's a different story with other data structures.

Comment: Obviously you can't resize or free the array when there are unowned references around as well. The owner has to wait for all the unowned references to go out of scope first.